# Script change without the use of web?

Tags: android, fonts

I want  to start to work on a android app,which will give the present english questions in other required languages.So anybody worked with Fonts please help me in this.I don have a correct idea how to start it?

Comment: I want to write the question in english and while parsing the string and should display the appropriate in my native language.Eg:'Kagaz' in hindi means 'paper',so I would type 'Kagaz' it is displayed in Hindi.

Comment: Actually initially had been thinking of directly converting a English question,by storing its equivalent question in database.But again how to store is a problem.Any help to proceed is greatly appreciated.